# How can I prove this version of the Martinkiewicz Zygmund Inequality, preferably from the Khintchine Inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

A text I was reading recently quoted the following version of the Martinkiewicz-Zygmund Inequality, for which I have not been able to find a proof:

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be centered, independent random variables. Then we have
$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^p \leq C (\sqrt p)^p \mathbb{E} \left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\right)^p$$

A few notes:

- Cauchy-Schwarz does not work because it introduces a factor of $(\sqrt n)^p$.
- It obviously fails if the $X_i$ are not independent or not centered.
- It is strongly reminiscent of the Khintchine inequality, which states that if $\epsilon_i$ are independent Rademacher random variables (ie, taking the value $\pm 1$ with 50/50 probability), and $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$, then 
  $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i x_i\right)^p \leq  C (\sqrt p)^p \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{p/2}$$
  there is a straightforward generalization of this inequality to the Martinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality above, provided the $X_i$ are not just centered but symmetric. However, I have not been able to prove the full strength statement.
- One potential approach I thought would work would be to extend the proof of the Khintchine inequality to work not just for scaled Rademacher random variables but for any centered random variables taking 2 values, but this has proven difficult.

Any help would be appreciated. I would just like to see a proof of the referenced Martinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality, but I would especially like it if it was a corollary of the Khintchine inequality.

EDIT: I've decided to include some of my approach, so that maybe someone can just finish it up. If we try to extend the proof of the Khintchine inequality to work not just for scaled Rademacher random variables but for any centered random variables taking 2 values, following the idea of proof in

http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~minilek/cs229r/fall15/lec/lec11.pdf ,

then it suffices to show that for each $X_i$, which is centered and only takes 2 values, we can find a random variable $g_i$ such that

1. $g_i$ is independent of $X_j$ for all $j$ (including $j=i$) and of every $g_j$ for $j \neq i$,
2. $g_i X_i$ is normally distributed with the same variance as $X_i$,
3. and $\mathbb{E} g_i >b >0$ for some constant $b$ independent of $n$, $p$, or the distributions of any $X_i$ or $g_i$.

But I have had difficulty in proving the existence of such a collection of $g_i$'s.

Comment: @shalop maybe I'm missing something but it seems this result is not quite what I need; you showed the p norm of the sum is bounded by $n^{1/2}$ times the $p$ norm of one (assuming the $X_i$ are identically distributed, which I have not), which is an improvement on the factor of $n$ given by the triangle inequality, but I need the $p$ norm of the ($\ell^1$) sum bounded by the p norm of the $\ell^2$ sum.

Comment: So is there any reason that the most general form of the inequality (i.e. Burkholder-Davis-Gundy) wouldn’t suffice for your purposes? E.g. as proved [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality/amp/)?

Comment: @shalop now I see that Burkholder-Davis-Gundy Inequality does the trick, thank you.

Comment: Ok, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98515/what-is-the-optimal-growth-of-the-constant-in-bdg) for a discussion of the optimal constant in BDG.